# MySQL Inner Join Results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question regarding Inner Joins in MySQl.From my limited understanding of MySQL, The results table produced by an inner join contains only rows that existed in both tables. That is to say for instance, if table1 contains a row for Joe and a row for Sally, and table2 contains only a row for Sally, an inner join would contain only one row: the row for Sally.

For Example:

In a database which contains 2 tables,

Table 1(Pet)

```
petName petType
Unicorn Horse
Pegasus Horse
Lion Cat
```

Table 2(Color)

```
petName petColor
Unicorn white
Unicorn silver
Fish Gold
```

Using the query

```
SELECT * FROM Pet,Color WHERE Pet.petName = Color.petName
```

Why is the result of the query?

```
petName petType petName petColor
Unicorn Horse   Unicorn white
Unicorn Horse   Unicorn silver
```

Why is there a " Unicorn Horse" in the second row when there is only 1 "Unicorn Horse" in table 1? Would i be correct in saying that MySQL matches the term "Unicorn" in both table 1 AND table 2, and lists the rows in both tables that have the word "Unicorn". However as doing so would result in

```
petName petType petName petColor
Unicorn Horse   Unicorn white
<   NULL   >   Unicorn silver
```

MySQL automatically replaces the  value with the row "Unicorn Horse" in table one since it matches the "Unicorn" keyword used in the query?

If so, what would be the point of this, as MySQL would only be giving me redundant data in the second row which i have no use for? Also, would i be able to work around this by using

```
SELECT * FROM Pet LEFT JOIN Color
ON Pet.petName=Color.petName
WHERE Pet.petName="Unicorn"?
```

I came across this example in PHP & MYSQL for Dummies and couldn't seem to get it.
I would appreciate it if some kind soul could clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you executed `SELECT * from Pet, Color` (without the `WHERE` clause), you would get the following back:

```
petName petType petName petColor
Unicorn Horse   Unicorn white
Pegasus Horse   Unicorn white
Lion    Cat     Unicorn white
Unicorn Horse   Unicorn silver
Pegasus Horse   Unicorn silver
Lion    Cat     Unicorn silver
Unicorn Horse   Fish    Gold
Pegasus Horse   Fish    Gold
Lion    Cat     Fish    Gold
```

This is called a `CROSS JOIN`; the SQL server will take each row from table 1 and match it to every row in table 2.

When you add `WHERE Pet.petName = Color.petName`, the SQL server will filter out all rows where the clause is untrue. As such, since the only `petName` with a defined `petColor` is `Unicorn`, you are left with

```
petName petType petName petColor
Unicorn Horse   Unicorn white
Unicorn Horse   Unicorn silver
```

Had your query instead been `WHERE Pet.petName != Color.petName`, you would have the complement, or

```
petName petType petName petColor
Pegasus Horse   Unicorn white
Lion    Cat     Unicorn white
Pegasus Horse   Unicorn silver
Lion    Cat     Unicorn silver
Unicorn Horse   Fish    Gold
Pegasus Horse   Fish    Gold
Lion    Cat     Fish    Gold
```

If you wanted only one row from Pet where a Color is defined, you could use

```
SELECT * FROM Pet 
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Color where Color.petName = Pet.petName)
```

which would return

```
petName petType
Unicorn Horse
```

This query essentially means "select all rows from `Pet` where there is at least one `Color` defined for that pet, by name".

This is called a semi-join, because the SQL server may be doing a join with `Color` behind the scenes, but no data from `Color` is returned in the result set. Since no `Color` data is returned, you will get each row from `Pet` only once, regardless of the number of `Color` rows defined for any given `petName`.

Comment: Does SELECT * FROM Pet WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Color where Color.petName = Pet.petName) translate in plain english, into " select the row(s) in the table Pet, where the data in the column petName matches the data in the column petName in the table Color"? I'm asking this because i'm still not too sure on the syntax for MySQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The result is as expected. You are joining the two tables with column `PetName` on both tables. `Unicorn Horse` From table `Pet` shows twice in the result set because it has matches on two records on table `Color`.

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

Where there are "multiple rows on one side per single row on the other", then the single row values are repeated.

So this is correct:

```
petName petType petName petColor
Unicorn Horse   Unicorn white
Unicorn Horse   Unicorn silver
```

SQL can not generate this with an INNER JOIN.

```
petName petType petName petColor
Unicorn Horse   Unicorn white
<   NULL   >   Unicorn silver
```

It is that simple.

Comment: sorry to interrupt but doing right join does not give the result you showed.

Comment: here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f564e/2 `unicorn` has one match on the other table.

Comment: unfortuantely, it will not still give you `null` value.

Comment: @Zeus: ah yes, I'm being dumb today

Comment: You can get this result with `SELECT *
FROM Pet RIGHT JOIN Color ON Pet.petName = Color.petName AND Color.petColor = 'white'
where Color.petColor <> 'Gold'`, but the query is tightly-coupled to the data, and almost completely meaningless. I'm not sure why you'd want this.

Answer (score 0):

This is as expected.

Your query is joining the petName columns from each table and returning a result where it matches. Here it finds a match from the Pet table with name `Unicorn Horse` in the Color table with color `white` and then it finds a second match from the Pet table with name `Unicorn Horse` in the Color table with color `silver`

Answer (score 0):

It's not that MySQL is filling in null data on the second row.

Your query is literally "Give me everything from both tables where PetName is horse.

As far as MySQL is concerned, it doesn't know that you want the 1st unicorn row in pet to be white and then have an extra unicorn that doesn't match anything be silver.  Instead it says "I've got this unicorn that has 2 attributes, white and silver.  And based on my first table, I know that all unicorns are horses. So I have a white horse unicorn and a silver horse unicorn."

As for the purpose, it's so you can remove redundant data. For example, if every business has 1 address but multiple sales people, you don't want to store the same address on each sales person because then when it's time to make a change, you have to update a lot of records.

Instead you could say "Testco is at 123 Main street. Bob, John, Sally and Frank are all sales people at Testco." Then the answer to the question of "What is Bob's address" is simply "123 Main street" But you look at the Testco record to get that and not at Bob's record.

Answer (score 0):

You have one unicorn pet that comes in two colours, so two rows.
If you added another row to Pet with petname of unicorn and a type of mythical creature, you would have got four.

If you are thinking hiding repeating data, that is a presentation issue. Each one is still a unicorn, you are simply not displaying that because you already have. The only way to do that is 'know' that it is the same as the one above.